# Extract complete country name from a string and make it as a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data as below.How to convert the below into a dataframe. I need the Country name(some country names has comma inbetween)as first column and other values as each columns.

Input is a txt file with many countries

**Czech Republic**`,22,22,22,21,21,21,21,21,19,18,16,14,13,12,11,11,10,9`
**Congo,Dem.Rep.**`,275,306,327,352,376,411,420,466,472,528,592,643,697,708,710,702,692,666`
**Congo,Rep.**`,209,222,231,243,255,269,424,457,367,545,313,354,402,509,477,482,511,485`

Output should be a dataframe with country name as first column

```
Czech Republic  22  22  22  21  21  21  21  21  19  18  16  14  13  12  11  11  10  9

Congo,Rep.      209 222 231 243 255 269 424 457 367 545 313 354 402 509 477 482 511 485

Congo, Dem.Rep. 275 306 327 352 376 411 420 466 472 528 592 643 697 708 710 702 692 666
```

Comment: Is the input a whole string?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : yes

Comment: And the output is also a string to the command line?

Comment: @Ofer Arial : it should be dataframe with country name as first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) (no problem if it is `.txt file`) with some separator which is not in values like `|` for `Series`, then [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) country names to one column and another values [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `,`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""Czech Republic,22,22,22,21,21,21,21,21,19,18,16,14,13,12,11,11,10,9 
Congo,Dem.Rep.,275,306,327,352,376,411,420,466,472,528,592,643,697,708,710,702,692,666 
Congo,Rep.,209,222,231,243,255,269,424,457,367,545,313,354,402,509,477,482,511,485"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
s = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="|", header=None, squeeze=True)
print (s)
0    Czech Republic,22,22,22,21,21,21,21,21,19,18,1...
1    Congo,Dem.Rep.,275,306,327,352,376,411,420,466...
2    Congo,Rep.,209,222,231,243,255,269,424,457,367...
Name: 0, dtype: object

df = s.str.extract('([A-Za-z ,.]+)([0-9,]+)', expand=True)
df[0] = df[0].str.strip(',')
df = df.set_index(0)[1].str.split(',', expand=True).rename_axis(None).reset_index()
#reset column names by 0,1,2... 
df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
print (df)
               0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12  \
0  Czech Republic   22   22   22   21   21   21   21   21   19   18   16   14   
1  Congo,Dem.Rep.  275  306  327  352  376  411  420  466  472  528  592  643   
2      Congo,Rep.  209  222  231  243  255  269  424  457  367  545  313  354   

    13   14   15   16   17   18  
0   13   12   11   11   10    9  
1  697  708  710  702  692  666  
2  402  509  477  482  511  485
```

---

If need `index` with countries:

```
df = df.set_index(0)[1].str.split(',', expand=True).rename_axis(None)
print (df)
                 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11  \
Czech Republic   22   22   22   21   21   21   21   21   19   18   16   14   
Congo,Dem.Rep.  275  306  327  352  376  411  420  466  472  528  592  643   
Congo,Rep.      209  222  231  243  255  269  424  457  367  545  313  354   

                 12   13   14   15   16   17  
Czech Republic   13   12   11   11   10    9  
Congo,Dem.Rep.  697  708  710  702  692  666  
Congo,Rep.      402  509  477  482  511  485
```

Solution be regex from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42175108/2901002) - it is possible use it as `sep` parameter, only `engine='python'` is necessary because warning:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO


temp=u"""Czech Republic,22,22,22,21,21,21,21,21,19,18,16,14,13,12,11,11,10,9 
Congo,Dem.Rep.,275,306,327,352,376,411,420,466,472,528,592,643,697,708,710,702,692,666 
Congo,Rep.,209,222,231,243,255,269,424,457,367,545,313,354,402,509,477,482,511,485"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=",(?=\d)", header=None, engine='python')

print (df)
               0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12  \
0  Czech Republic   22   22   22   21   21   21   21   21   19   18   16   14   
1  Congo,Dem.Rep.  275  306  327  352  376  411  420  466  472  528  592  643   
2      Congo,Rep.  209  222  231  243  255  269  424  457  367  545  313  354   

    13   14   15   16   17   18  
0   13   12   11   11   10    9  
1  697  708  710  702  692  666  
2  402  509  477  482  511  485
```

Answer (score 1):

[jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael)'s answer is the way to go if you want the complete output asap.

If you want to really understand some simpler code, try doing the following:

1. Split the string into some lists like this:

   ```
   data = "Czech Republic..."
   lines = data.split('\n')
   rows = []
   ```
2. then iterate over the lines, and append them to a list of lists:

   ```
   def is_number(s):
       try:
           float(s)
           return True
       except ValueError:
           return False

   for line in lines:
       temp = line.split(',')
       if is_number(temp[1]):
           rows.append([''.join(temp[:2])].extend(temp[2:])) // ignoring the first ',' delimiter if the second column is a number
       else:
           rows.append(temp)
   ```
3. then use this list of lists and read the following pandas [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) documentation, on how to [preety-print](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) it. (**Hint**: make the list of lists a dict first)

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `re.split()` function and labeled data structure with *columns*:

```
import pandas as pd, re

s = '''
Czech Republic,22,22,22,21,21,21,21,21,19,18,16,14,13,12,11,11,10,9
Congo,Dem.Rep.,275,306,327,352,376,411,420,466,472,528,592,643,697,708,710,702,692,666
Congo,Rep.,209,222,231,243,255,269,424,457,367,545,313,354,402,509,477,482,511,485
'''
data = []
for l in s.split('\n'):
    if l: data.append(re.split(r',(?=\d)', l))

# setting output options
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 20)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Country name'] + list(range(len(data[0][1:]))))

print(df)
```

The output:

```
     Country name    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17
0  Czech Republic   22   22   22   21   21   21   21   21   19   18   16   14   13   12   11   11   10    9
1  Congo,Dem.Rep.  275  306  327  352  376  411  420  466  472  528  592  643  697  708  710  702  692  666
2      Congo,Rep.  209  222  231  243  255  269  424  457  367  545  313  354  402  509  477  482  511  485
```